# How can I find conversations in MS Exchange using c#

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I need to get all conversations from MS Exchange Mailbox and extract each email from the conversations.
How can I do that using C# and Exchange API?
The issue is that I have Exchange 2010, but the main conversaton operation are in Exchage 2013.

Answer (score 0):

The FindConversation operation in EWS was introduced in Exchange 2010 SP1  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn610351(v=exchg.150).aspx there are some differences between versions but it should work okay (you need to make sure the Schema version in your request say 2010_SP1 or greator). The underlying ID properties this operations uses are available using Extended properties https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee204279(v=exchg.80).aspx so you can use those as an alternative using a SearchFilter.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks Glen. But how can I retriev a body from each email of the conversation? We have a lot of methods for body text, but that's only in Exchange 2013. How can I do that in 2010?

Comment: The only way to get the Body is to do a GetItem request so in the managed API that would involve using the Load or LoadPropertiesFromItems methods once you have gotten the EWSId of the Item with FindItems or findconversations.